# Intels Open Source uPNP SDK Has absolutely 0 documentation, why?

Tags: c#, java, .net, python, objective-c

basically, here is the address... http://opentools.homeip.net/dev-tools-for-upnp

they are the recommended dll's to use for upnp as they implement the standards better then microsofts upnp.dll - but the intels open source upnp tools have absolutely no documentation, not on their website, not on any other website. is there a reason for this and does anyone know anything more about this issue? i've tried emailing them, no response.

also, they have some non-programming 15 minute youtube videos about some basic GUI tools, but thats about it, nothing programming related, and guessing how their classes work and interact with one another has been a real pain and isn't panning out.

if any of you know anything further on this, would be appreciated.

the reason i ask is because, currently, i am trying to solve this problem:
[Getting IP Address using UPnP InvokeAction not returning anything, help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022939/getting-ip-address-using-upnp-invokeaction-not-returning-anything-help)

... and am thinking of moving away from microsofts upnp.dll in favor of intels upnp dll as a last resort (if i can't solve above problem), but to do that i would need to learn how to use intel's upnp dll. if somehow there is documentation, i would love to see it, thanks.

thanks

Comment: Off-topic, you should ask Intel why they have not provided documentation or where you can find it, if available.

Comment: ive tried all of that, i am asking programmers since there are bound to be people using it, and they can tell me how they solved the problem. it is absolutely not off topic! your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194216/what-do-you-do-when-your-team-leader-doesnt-know-something-simple is more off topic then mine could ever be, argument would follow: why don't you ask him instead?

Comment: The question is valid but should ask about code help or where to find some documentation/examples instead of asking why there are no documentation.

Comment: i thought the where was implied? will edit.

Comment: See http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=75951&o=a&s=lr

Comment: I could not replicate that mainly because I don't understand what he is saying entirely. Do you?

Comment: @Erx_VB: You might want to edit this a bit more, to ask directly "where can I find documentation for..." instead of "why is there no documentation" as your title currently says. It's a reasonable question, and I understand your frustration; you just might want to make it a little less inflammatory.

Comment: @Jefromi thanks for your advice, but does it really sound inflammatory? it didn't come across to me that way at all even when i read it over a year later. I can still change it if ppl think so.

Comment: also, to note, after reading the link provided by leppie - it seems as though documentation comes with the source code - no idea why they would include it with source and not SDK, and apparently you have to do some kind of complex rain dance routine in order to make it work in the source code package, and perhaps if it even is in the non-source SDK package, it may not be visible for this reason, there surely were no references to it or mentions of it anywhere apart from people asking about its absence. Ok, i'm off to work on my conjuration skills.   :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a late answer, but in this post:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=50740

The attach a .chm with a generated reference documentation. Don't forget to unblock the file (right-click, properties, unblock) before opening, otherwise you won't be able to read the pages.

Comment: thanks for the info, i always love checking old posts for new information, so appreciate it even more. just a quick question, i'm on win7 and downloaded & viewed the document, didnt work as expected, then i shut it down and did the right-click properties and clicked "unblock" and its still not working, rechecked to see if it was unblocked, and it must be since the unblocking button is no longer there. any ideas why this may be? also, just curious, why on earth would intel not publish the documentation on their website, perhaps with their software or code? cant fathom this lol.

Comment: This documentation is actually just generated from the source code inline documentation. I'm guessing that's why. IF you open the source solution in Visual Studio I think you would be able to see a similar reference documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There just so happens to be an ENTIRE BOOK that discusses and demonstrates the Intel UPnP Stack/Library. This book is specific to the C implementation of UPnP by Intel.

The book is called:

[UPnP Design by Example](https://noggin.intel.com/intelpress/categories/books/upnp-design-example) by Michael Jeronimo and Jack Weast

[Amazon.com link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0971786119)

Hope this helps somebody out. It took me quite a while to find documentation on the Intel Library. Actual use of code from the Intel UPnP stack begins on page 202 of the book.

Comment: We ended up writing our own UPnP implementation as we only needed the client side.  We did it in C# and it is much more stable for us.  You may want to do the same.