# Can Intel's Open Source UPnP Library be Used with VB6?

Tags: c#, java, .net, vb.net, vb6

Just a question, as I was unable to register the related upnp.dll provided by the intel open source upnp tools package (as provided here: http://opentools.homeip.net/dev-tools-for-upnp ) from the VB6 references dialog, it said something to the effect of "can't register .dll", but since it is written in (i think) C or C++ I figured there would be a way to make it useable somehow.

I am mainly thinking of moving to intel's upnp because microsofts upnp.dll is not letting me progress further due to the following issue (works in .NET but not in VB6):
[Getting IP Address using UPnP InvokeAction not returning anything, help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022939/getting-ip-address-using-upnp-invokeaction-not-returning-anything-help)

Would anyone know how I would go about getting intel's upnp.dll (registers correctly in C# and VB.NET) to work in VB6?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a file called upnp.dll in the windows\system32 folder on my 32bit XP install. I KNOW I haven't installed any intel SDKs.

I can regsvr32 that file, add a reference to it in VB6 and view the exposed classes just fine.

Is the UPNP.dll you're talking about something else? Could you make use of the version that appears to be included with windows?

Comment: there is a ms upnp.dll which is the one you encountered, there is also another upnp.dll installed by intels open source SDK in the program files directory's open source directory, you will encounter this upnp.dll if you instal intel's upnp developer tools as can be found if you follow the first link in my post.  the problem i've encountered is that with microsofts version, i am running into a problem (as described in second link in my post) and i am considering (and would like to) use intel's upnp.dll instead, as an alternative, so that i could bypass the problem i'm having with ms's upnp.dll

Comment: Looks like you tried the variations I would have Ie dim xouts() as variant and dim xouts as variant. From the docs, it looks like the in and out both expect the same thing, but that's obviously not the case, have you tried the xins argument as an array, and the xouts as a simple variant, or vice versa?

Comment: Also, it might not be enough to just DIM the array, you may need to actually set a value of the applicable types into each element. this from the Docs   "When an application invokes the method InvokeAction, it includes a list of arguments that should match the arguments expected by the service. The Control Point maps these VARIANT arguments to the required type. The following table shows the mappings that are used...." Just a guess, though

Comment: This post might give some clues. It's c# but just in case you haven't seen it.   http://www.tonews.com/thread/1785672/microsoft/public/upnp/invokeaction_and_c.html